# Returning a value from a promise: callback or promise?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, ms-office, office-js

(* I modified my initial question... *)

I have an asynchronous function `calculate` which re-calculates a Excel workbook and prints how long it takes.

Then, I want to make the function to return the calculation time, so that I could record it. It regards making an asynchronous function return a value. I read several threads, and write the following 2 ways, which work:

```
function calculate1 (mode, fn) {
    return Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        ctx.workbook.application.calculate(mode);
        var before = performance.now();
        return ctx.sync().then(function() {
            var after = performance.now();
            var t = after - before;
            document.getElementById("b").value += 'inside: ' + t + '\n'; 
            fn(t);
        })
    })
}

function calculate2 (mode) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        return Excel.run(function (ctx) {
            ctx.workbook.application.calculate(mode);
            var before = performance.now();
            return ctx.sync().then(function() {
                var after = performance.now();
                var t = after - before;
                document.getElementById("b").value += 'inside: ' + t + '\n';
                resolve(t); })
            })
    })
}
```

Here is the test:

```
function test () {
    var a = [];
    var pm = new OfficeExtension.Promise(function(resolve, reject) { resolve (null); });

    pm
        .then(function() { return calculate1('FullRebuild', function (t) {
            a.push(t); }); })
        .then(function() { return calculate1('FullRebuild', function (t) {
            a.push(t); }); })
        .then(function() { return calculate2('FullRebuild').then(function (result) {
            a.push(result); }); })
        .then(function() { return calculate2('FullRebuild').then(function (result) {
            a.push(result); }); })
        .then(function() {
            document.getElementById("b").value += a.toString() + '\n'; });
}
```

I guess `calculate1` uses `callback`, while `calculate2` uses `promise`. Could anyone tell me which way is better?

Additionally, is `fn(t)` (resp., `resolve(t)`) in the right place, or should I wrap it in another `then`?

PS: `Excel.run` and `ctx.sync()` are functions of [JavaScript API for Office](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-javascript-programming-overview); they both return a promise.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it. You are mixing callback and promises. I would suggest let calculate resolve `t`, which is what you want.

Comment: My initial way by callback was not wrong (the error message was due to something else). Please see my updates...

Comment: The one you like more is "better".

Comment: I mean, isn't there anything redundant in one way or the other? Moreover, are the two ways fundamentally the same or different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`calculate1()` is a bad mixture of promises and callbacks, and `calculate2()` is exhibiting the [Explicit Promise Construction Antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it).

Here is how you can correctly use promises without any extra waste:

```
function calculate1 (mode) {
    return Excel.run(function (ctx) {
        ctx.workbook.application.calculate(mode);
        var before = performance.now();

        return ctx.sync().then(function() {
            var after = performance.now();
            var t = after - before;
            document.getElementById("b").value += 'inside: ' + t + '\n'; 

            return t;
        });
    });
}
```

And then you can consume it like this. Note that it uses considerably fewer functions than your attempt:

```
return calculate1('FullRebuild')
    .then(function(res) { 
        a.push(res);
        return calculate1('FullRebuild'); 
     })
    .then(function(res) { 
        a.push(res);
        return calculate1('FullRebuild'); 
     })
    .then(function(res) { 
        a.push(res);
        return calculate1('FullRebuild'); 
     })
    .then(function(res) {
        a.push(res);
        document.getElementById("b").value += a.toString() + '\n'; 
    });
```

Comment: The `Promise` constructor might actually be necessary to wrap `Excel.run`. Still, to avoid the antipattern it should look something like `resolve(ctx.sync().then(…))`

Comment: The code works... I see `resolve(t)` is very often used to pass a value to `function (res) {...}` in `then`. Whereas, you directly use `return t`, why is it possible and how is it called?

Comment: @SoftTimur The `resolve()` function is needed for creating promises out of non-promise code. Since `Excel.run()` and `ctx.sync()` are promise-based, you don't need `resolve()` here. The reason this works is that `then()` returns a promise that resolves to the value that's returned _inside_ the `then()`. A promise is returned inside the `then()`, the promise returned by `then()` will "adopt" that promise and its resolution or rejection.

Comment: @Bergi The [documentation](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/excel/excel-add-ins-programming-overview.md) says _The run method takes in RequestContext and returns a promise (typically, just the result of ctx.sync())_. While it doesn't explicitly say that its result is the result of whatever is returned within its callback, that does appear to be the case based on SoftTimur's comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an asynchronous function to return a value - instead of passing a callback to it - the return value needs to be wrapped in a promise and resolved like in your second example.

The convenience of the promise is that it avoids callback nesting -> when a callback needs another callback...
And the way Errors are propagated to the closest Promise.catch() block

```
function calculate2 (mode) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { 

        Excel.run(function (ctx) {       
           ctx.workbook.application.calculate(mode);
           var before = performance.now();

           ctx.sync().then(function() { 
               var after = performance.now(); 
               var t = after - before;  

               resolve(t); 
            })
        })
    })
}

calculate2('FullRebuild')
    .then(function (t) {
         document.getElementById("b").value += 'inside: ' + t + '\n';
         // the return value of a promise resolver is wrapped in a promise too
         // and the value of t will be available as parameter of the following .then(funtion(t)) block
         return t; 
 })
.catch(function(err) {
    // Addresses potential async errors raised since calling calculate2()
 });
```